# Why does openMP hang on barrier within a while cycle?

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I've got the following code:

```
    int working_threads=1;
#pragma omp parallel
    {   
        int my_num=omp_get_thread_num()+1;
        int idle=false;
        while(working_threads>0) {
            if(my_num==1)
                working_threads=0;
#pragma omp barrier                                                                                                                       
        }   
    }
```

If I run it, it every now and then hangs on the barrier. The more threads, the more likely this is to happen. I've tried to debug it with printf and it seems that sometimes not all threads are executed and thus the barrier waits for them forever. This happens in the first iteration, the second one is obviously never run.

Is it an invalid piece of code? If so, how can I change it? I need to run a while loop in parallel. It is not known how many loops will be executed before, but it is guaranteed that all threads will have the same number of iterations.

Comment: _"... it is guaranteed that all threads will have the same number of iterations"_ - is this an intrinsic property of the loop or is it achieved only by using a shared variable as in the demonstrated case? If the former, simply make the conditional variable private.

Comment: The latter, it is done by testing against a shared variable. That's also the reason of the race-condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite your attempt to synchronize with the barrier, you do have a race condition on `working_threads` that can easily lead to unequal amount of iterations:

```
thread 0                             | thread 1
...                                  | ...
while (working_threads > 0) [==true] | ...
    if (my_num == 1) [==true]        | ...
        working_threads = 0          | ...
                                     | while (working_threads > 0) [==false]
    [hangs waiting for barrier]      | [hangs trying to exit from parallel]
```

To fix your specific code, you would have to also add a barrier between the while-condition-check and `working_threads = 0`.

```
#pragma omp parallel
    {   
        int my_num=omp_get_thread_num()+1;
        int idle=false;
        while(working_threads>0) {
#pragma omp barrier      
            if(my_num==1)
                working_threads=0;
#pragma omp barrier                                                                                                                       
        }   
    }
```

Note that the code is not exactly the most idiomatic or elegant solution. Depending on your specific work-sharing problem, there may be a better approach. Also you must ensure that `worker_threads` is written only by a single thread - or use atomics when writing.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure how to make it more idiomatic. The idea is that each thread gets an interval. However, it is not known in advance how much time a particular interval takes. Therefore every interval is divided into more iteration which are computed one-by-one in the while. If there is an IDLE thread, it simply gets part of an interval from someone else for the nex iteration.

Comment: @knezi, can't you use tasks? Those are well-suited for recursive problems such as yours.

Comment: It sounds like you might have even more race conditions if you are trying to implement work-stealing. Tasks may be a solution, but I don't understand your underlying problem sufficiently enough to be more specific.

Comment: I'm new to openMP and I don't know how tasks work. I'll check them out. Thank you for the suggestion.